# How to check for different tile with unity tilemaps?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Every example I've found only to do with the new tilemap system only looks for a tile using GetTile and then checks it against itself using "this". EG.

```
private bool HasOtherTile(ITilemap tilemap, Vector3Int position)
{
    return tilemap.GetTile(position) == this;
}
```

I want to be able to check for a other specific tiles instead. Such as a WallTile.asset tile with a my `public class WallTile : TileBase` script attached I've created. I'm really stuck on how to do this.

I've tried using

```
gameObject.AddComponent(WaterTile)

TileBase tileTest = gameObject.AddComponent(WallTile);


private bool HasRoadTile(ITilemap tilemap, Vector3Int position)
{
    TileBase tileTest = gameObject.AddComponent(WaterTile);
    return tilemap.GetTile(position) == tileTest;
}
```

But this doesnt seem to work.

I've also tried `ScriptableObject.CreateInstance(WaterTile)` which also doesn't work.

@Sandro Figo
[The GetTile method doesn't seem to have an extension method for gameObject it seems.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNCNA.png)

[It returns "T Tile of type T placed at the cell."](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Tilemaps.Tilemap.GetTile.html)

Answer (score 0):

**To check for the tile type at a position:**

```
public bool IsTileOfType<T>(ITilemap tilemap, Vector3Int position) where T : TileBase
{
    TileBase targetTile = tilemap.GetTile(position);

    if (targetTile != null && targetTile is T)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

**Regarding gameobject of a tile:**

Your tiles must inherit from Tile class not TileBase in order to manipulate its gameobject.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
private bool HasWallTile(ITilemap tilemap, Vector3Int position)
{
    return tilemap.GetTile(position).gameObject.GetComponent<WallTile>() != null;
}
```

Comment: The GetTile method doesn't seem to have an extension method for gameObject it seems




https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNCNA.png
It returns "T Tile of type T placed at the cell." https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Tilemaps.Tilemap.GetTile.html